# What is the order of $g^r$ in terms of order of $g$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose $g \in G$ has order $o(g)$ and let $r$ be a divisor of $o(g)$, what is the order of $g^r$ ?

I’m able to find answers that give me what I think I need but its difficult for me to decipher all the notation and precisely what the answers are trying to tell me

What I know is:

- Order of $g$ is the minimal $m$ such that $g^m=e$.
- $r|m$ , so there exists a $k \in \Bbb Z$ st $m=kr$
- I conclude that $g^{rk}=e$ with $rk=m$, thus $r=m/k$
- So the order of $g^r$ is $m/k$

I just doubt every abstract Algebra thought I have, so naturally I feel that this is incorrect.

Any Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Call $n=o(g)$. One  standard result in algebra says that $$o(g^r)=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,r)}$$

*Proof:*  Let $k=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,r)}$.  $$(g^r)^k=(g^r)^{\frac{n}{\gcd(n,r)}}=(g^n)^{\frac{r}{\gcd(n,r)}}=e^{\frac{r}{\gcd(n,r)}}=e$$

Now try to prove $k$ is the least such power!

Comment: Thx ill try that